# Moving apps to a new ipad

Tags: ipad

I have a personal iPad with some work apps on it.  I just received an iPad from my employer.  The 2 have different iCloud accounts.  How can I move work apps from my personal iPad to the work iPad without having to pay for them again?  It only affects a couple of apps

Answer (score 2):

In the Store-App, log in with the account that was used to buy the apps. Then you can re-download the apps without paying (using the bought-tab, or just searching for the app).

Comment: Thanks, but now how do I log in under the account that I purchased the apps? I do not see a place to change that information.

Comment: There should be a setting for this in Settings > App Store